# Difference in List Objects Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, list, pandas, set

I Have a Data Frame as descibed Below

```
Dt_Frame =  pd.DataFrame()

AIDList = ['ID1','ID2','ID3','ID4','ID5']
BIDList = ['ID1','ID2','ID3']

Dt_Frame = Dt_Frame.append ({'Country': 'USA', 'Schedule':  'Daily', 'Date': '2016-12-07', 'Status': 'Active','AListIDs' : AIDList ,'BListIDs' : BIDList}, ignore_index=True)
```

I have a add a Column `Difference` which shows the Differences in 2 columns namely AIDList and BIDList ,Which in this case is `'ID4,'ID5'`,Which i think Sets Can be used in case, But Not Sure How do i do it? AIDList and BIDList types is List.And also How can i add One more column `Numb_Items`which gives the Number of objects in the list AIDList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add new column, you can `Dt_Frame["newColumnName"] = value`.

Regarding the `set` difference, your intuition is right. First, you can use `apply` to convert the `list`'s into `set`'s

```
A = Dt_Frame["AListIDs"].apply(set)
B = Dt_Frame["BListIDs"].apply(set)
```

Then applying minus on each side will give you the difference w.r.t the other set. That is

```
A - B

0    {ID4, ID5}
dtype: object

B - A

0    {}
dtype: object
```

For symmetric difference we'll need `A,B` to be in the same `DataFrame` (either for the `symmetric_difference` method or for the `|` operator):

```
# We add two new columns
Dt_Frame["ASetIDs"] = A
Dt_Frame["BSetIDs"] = B

# We need to transpose since apply operates on columns
Dt_Frame[["ASetIDs", "BSetIDs"]].T.apply(lambda x: x.ASetIDs.symmetric_difference(x.BSetIDs))
```

Comment: Just a small Doubt, Is it required to transpose, can we do without transposing , Explicitly Setting axis as Column ???

Comment: You're right. You can use `axis=1` as in `Dt_Frame[["ASetIDs", "BSetIDs"]].apply(lambda x: x.ASetIDs.symmetric_difference(x.BSetIDs), axis=1)`